# dialog.showSaveDialog doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, electron

So, I'm trying to create a simple Save Dialog, where the user can select a location and filename, and it will create a file at that specified location.

I've followed the docs, and also checked out some tutorials, the code is exact same, but apparently in my case when I open the dialog, select a location and click Save, I don't get any response back in the callback of dialog.showSaveDialog method.

Sorry if this is a noob mistake, I'm just starting into Electron.

Here's my code:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote

const createBtn = document.getElementById('create_btn')

createBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  console.log('First Response: ', await dialog.showSaveDialog())

  dialog.showSaveDialog(path => {
    console.log('Second Response: ', path)
  })
})
```

And here is the complete console log:

```
First Response:  {}
```

Edit:
I've also tried this method, as per the latest docs. But no luck!

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote

const createBtn = document.getElementById('create_btn')

createBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  dialog.showSaveDialog({}).then((result) => {
    console.log('Second Response: ', result)
  }).catch((...args) => {
    console.warn('failed/rejected with', args)
  })
})
```

Electron: v7.1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you simply need to click on the `{}` in the console to expand the result ;)

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/8b64eb6913d7abf210df15764c224f36) an [Electron Fiddle](https://electronjs.org/fiddle) demonstrating `showSaveDialog`.

```html
<button id="save">Show save dialog</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

```js
// renderer.js
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

const outEl = document.getElementById('output');
function log(...args) {
  console.log(...args);
  outEl.innerText += args.join(' ');
}

const buttonEl = document.getElementById('save');
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const dialogOptions = {};
  try {
    const result = await dialog.showSaveDialog(dialogOptions);
    log('Save resolved:', result);
    const { filePath } = result;
    log('filePath -->', filePath);
  } catch (e) {
    log('Save failed:', e)
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems, I made the wrong understanding. Will remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
const { dialog, app } = require('electron')

...
const options = {}; // You can set this as your need
const result = await dialog.showSaveDialog(mainWindow, options);
```

You can set the **browserWindow** as firstParameter that will be set as parent of this dialog and next is the options as secondParameter.
You can check what **options** are available at tutorial docs or Electron guide.

Check this: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options

Comment: There is no longer any `callback` parameter in the function signature

Comment: hey, @iX3 what do you mean?

Comment: You said, "And 3rd parameter is callback function..." but [`dialog.showSaveDialog`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options) only accepts 2 arguments: `browserWindow` and `options`. It does not work with callbacks.

Comment: The reasons that I down-voted this answer were (1) technical error regarding callback -- that is, the code you provided won't actually work as intended on electron v7.x, (2) distracting comment about `browserWindow` which is irrelevant to the OP's problem, and (3) distracting code to set the optional `defaultPath` option, which is also unrelated to the question.

Comment: I just shared the exmaple

Comment: There was the callback function as parameter but from higher version it doesn't support. So I shared the final version at last

Comment: Are you saying that the code you included above is from electron documentation? If so, please include the URL. I do not see it in the API docs, and if it is part of the electron docs then it needs to be updated.

Comment: Code from this
https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-showsavedialog-tutorial/